# I tried to get the index of an element from Core Data, but it shows an error even I force unwrapped the value of the index

Tags: swift, core-data, option-type, predicate

I try to use a function to sorted the data in the Core Data, and get the `firstIndex` of the first element base on the predicate, but when I used `.firstIndex`, it shows:

> Value of type '((Filedetails) -> Array.Index?)?' (aka 'Optional<(Filedetails) -> Optional>') has no member 'compactMap'"

```
func countingLastOccurrence(filterkey1: String) -> Int {

        let context = PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext

        let fetchquest1 = NSFetchRequest<Filedetails>(entityName: "Filedetails")

        fetchquest1.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Filedetails.year, ascending: false), NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Filedetails.sequence, ascending: false)]

        fetchquest1.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == 1", filterkey1)

        let item1 = try? context.fetch(fetchquest1).firstIndex

       let item1a = item1.compactMap { Int($0) }

        return item1a
```

I had tried to force unwrapped the value, but it is error

> "Cannot assign value of type '(Filedetails) -> Array.Index?' (aka '(Filedetails) -> Optional') to type 'Int'"

```
var item1a: Int = 0
        if let item1 = try? context.fetch(fetchquest1).firstIndex {
            item1a  = item1
        }
        return item1a
```

I tried "if let" and "guard let"

```
guard let item1 = try? context.fetch(fetchquest1).firstIndex  else {
            return 0
        }
return item1
```

It still shows an error:

> Cannot convert return expression of type '(Filedetails) -> Array.Index?' (aka '(Filedetails) -> Optional') to return type 'Int'

If I used `.first` for the predicate, I can get the details of the data, but when I used `.firstIndex`, I can't get the result.

How can I get the index as a `Int` ?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your code generates **two** optionals, one by `try?` and one by `first(Index)`.

The first index of the *first element base on the predicate* is always zero so it doesn't make much sense to return the index especially to return 0 in case of an error.

Calling `compactMap` is also pointless because both input and output is an array. It just skips the `nil` *values*.

To avoid the double optional you could return an optional `Filedetails` item

```
func countingLastOccurrence(filterKey: String) -> Filedetails? {
    
    let context = PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<Filedetails>(entityName: "Filedetails")
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Filedetails.year, ascending: false), NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Filedetails.sequence, ascending: false)]
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == 1", filterKey)
    guard let result = try? context.fetch(request) else { return nil}
    return result.first
}
```

Or hand over the error to the caller

```
func countingLastOccurrence(filterKey: String) throws -> Filedetails? {
    
    let context = PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<Filedetails>(entityName: "Filedetails")
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Filedetails.year, ascending: false), NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Filedetails.sequence, ascending: false)]
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == 1", filterKey)
    return try context.fetch(request).first
}
```

Side note: Consider a better naming than the `1` and `1a` suffixes which are a bit confusing

Comment: Oh !!! you teach me an important concept, Thank you so much.